# Why doesn't python concatenate string literals with adjacent string variables?

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I'm curious why this works:

```
>>> "foo" "bar"
'foobar'
```

But this doesn't:

```
>>> str1 = "foo"
>>> str1 "bar"
    str1 "bar"
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I understand I can use a `+`, `''.join()`, etc. to concatenate a string variable. More asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Because Python [doesn't allow](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) such syntax. Period.

Comment: Concatenation of string literals is a compile-time operation.  Concatenation involving string variables is necessarily a run-time operation.